# sonata_type_collection is cleared on preSubmit

Tags: collections, types, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-3.2

Related to this issue : https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCoreBundle/issues/408, I have an unexpected behavior of a custom sonata_type_collection.

The collection is used as an EAV model to build dynamic forms througth a standard sonata_type_collection.

When submitting the form with an error (e.g. a mandatory field that is empty) the re-rendered form loose it's structure. The collection is built in a PRE_SET_DATA form events, but when submitting, the preSubmit event « destroy » the collection built in PRE_SET_DATA.

My question, is there a way to avoid the collection clearing at submit time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ResizeFormListener` attached to your form field is probably causing this behaviour as it removes empty rows from the collection when you submit the form.

You should add the `modifiable => false` option when adding your collection field to the `FormMapper`.

With this option the ResizeFormListener will not be attached thus empty collection elements won't be removed on submit.

Comment: Thanks. The type option « modifiable » solve my problem, the collection is not reset at preSubmit time.